# PyCharm acting funny

Tags: pycharm

I am a somewhat off-and-on user of pycharm and today I let the moths out and opened it up for the first time in a month. I wanted to create a project, so I did so, calling it Test. I then wanted to create a file in it, let's call it demo. However, I ran into trouble here. [image: Here is me clicking on Python File]

After I clicked this, it opened the normal dialogue box and I typed "Demo.py" and clicked ok. However, nothing happened. I clicked it again, and it said: [image]

So I said ok, it must have created it without indicating such, so I exit out of the dialogue and click on the file to view its contents, but whereas this would normally show an empty text field, it showed nothing. [image] It did not appear PyCharm was responding to this file (when I opened it separately in Idle, it worked fine). So, I deleted the application and redownloaded it to no avail (same errors). All this to say, do you experts have any idea how I can fix this? Thanks!

Felix

Comment: You should include PyCharm version...and the OS appears to be OSX. I'm running OSX too and PyCharm 2016.3.2 and when I create a Python file in an already existing project it immediately jumps to it showing the empty text file that you expect.

Comment: It either will jump to it when you create the file, or if you click once on a file it will not open it in my case, you have to double click on it in this case.

Comment: Right except when I make a new file nothing happens and when I click on the file that it creates (although never confirms this creation) I see nothing.

Comment: Have you tried to just delete the file and create a new one?

Comment: Yep. I deleted the file, deleted the project, deleted the application, still the same.